# Two instances raspberry

Tags: media-server

I'm wondering, does raspberry has the possibility to run two instances?

With two instances i mean, two separated os's, so i can output to two tvs and have one raspberry controlling my whole media center.

Is there any possibility?

**EDIT:**

Well, what i'm planning in my head.
I have two tvs which i want to connect to a raspberry pi to stream media through the local network. I want when one tv is using the raspberry pi, the other tv would be able to access it too using xbmc, twitch, youtube etc.

Any ideias?

Comment: Do you want to run both OS's at once on a single PI? If so this is highly unlikely to be possible. Perhaps explaining more about what you are trying to do would allow us to give you better answers.

Comment: @SteveRobillard ive edited to give you guys a better perspective to what i would like to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need at least two pis. Each only has one HDMI port and can only run one os/display at a time.

You effectively have three entities, the media server and two displays/thin clients. Raspberry pis can act as either a media server or a thin client (or both at once). So you can connect one pi to one display, have it run as a media server and client to that display and have the other pi connect to the first over the network and act just as a client.

XBMC can act as both a server and client, so you just need to get a second pi connected to the second display to connect to the first one. Note however that the pi is not very fast at network/disk access and streaming two streams over it might prove too much for it. If you find performance to be a problem you can setup a central media server (on low end hardware, possibly with more disk space) to act as the media server (with XBMC) and the two pis to just act as clients.

Comment: Infact i have my pc acting as a server which has a folder shared thorugh the NAT. Ok, so i will need two pis. Thanks.